# python regex: Put the space between digit and character

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have the following simple string:

```
a = "total net band width 13.5mm. 12.25mm 13.5mm 5mm 11.5mm speed"
```

How do I insert a space between 2 consecutive characters if one the first is a digit and the second is an alphabet?

Here is what I have tried so far using python regex:

```
    re.sub('\d+\.\d+', " ", a)
```

Desired output:

```
"total net band width 13.5 mm. 12.25 mm 13.5 mm 5 mm 11.5 mm speed"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a capturing group, using `(` and `)`.

Then put the contents of that group in the output, using `\1`:

```
re.sub(r'(\d+\.\d+)', r'\1 ', a)
```

Of course, that fails on `5mm` since there is no decimal component. Better to use a character class:

```
re.sub(r'(\d[\.\d]*)', r'\1 ', a)
```

If you want to be pendantic about rejecting inputs like `5..6` then some `?` qualifiers would be suitable.